# Function that assigns new value appears to initially work the first time, but doesn't appear to return to beginning of if statement the second time

Tags: javascript

I am in the middle of the Pig Dice problem and I am trying to use the function `switchPlayers()` to switch between player1 and player2. When clicking "Roll Dice", it appears to switch to the second player but then no longer switches to the first player. After re-working it a few times, I'm starting to think the issue may be that even if Player2 updates to `.isTurn = false` the function is longer being called? I appreciate any pointers here (Note, haven't worked on the New Game or Hold Button yet)Thank you!
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Msaldivia/xz501rjy/285/)

```js
//business logic for dice
function Dice() {
  this.diceValue = 1;
  this.roll = 0;
}

function Player() {
  this.score = 0;
  this.dice = new Dice()
  this.isTurn = true
}
//global Players
player1 = new Player();
player2 = new Player();

function switchPlayers() {
  if (player1.dice.roll === 0) {
    player1.isTurn = false;
  } else if (player2.dice.roll === 0) {
    player2.isTurn = false;
  }
}

Dice.prototype.rollDice = function() {
  this.diceValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  if (this.diceValue === 1) {
    this.roll = 0;
  } else {
    this.roll = this.diceValue;
  }
}

Player.prototype.calcScore = function() {
  this.dice.rollDice()
  if (this.dice.roll === 0) {
    switchPlayers();
  } else {
    this.score += this.dice.roll
  }
}

//ui logic 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.btn-roll").click(function(event) {
    if (player1.isTurn !== false) {
      player1.calcScore();
      $('#p1-total').html(player1.score);
      $('#p1-roll').html(player1.dice.roll);
    } else if (player2.isTurn === true) {
      player2.calcScore();
      $('#p2-total').html(player2.score);
      $('#p2-roll').html(player2.dice.roll)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <title>Pig Dice!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="player-1-panel active">
      <div class="player-name" id="name-0">Player 1</div>
      <div class="player1-score">
        <p>this roll points: <span id="p1-roll"></span></p>
        <p>
          total: <span id="p1-total"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="player-2-panel">
    <div class="player-name" id="name-1">Player 2</div>
    <div class="player1-score">
      <p>this roll: <span id="p2-roll"></span></p>
      <p>
        total: <span id="p2-total"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark"></i>New game</button>
  <button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
  <button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>
  <img src="img/die5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice die1">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use a  [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) rather than linking to a remote jsfiddle.

Comment: Why does `switchPlayer()` check the roll rather than `isTurn`?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your logic, i have reviewed your code, added some tips (button hold), so you could easily understant what i have done and increase yours skills:

```js
function initGame(){
  //selectRandomly wich players begins
  idToPlay = Math.floor((Math.random()*maxNumberPlayers));
  
  for(let p = 0;p < maxNumberPlayers;p++){
      let id = '#p' + p;
      $(id + '-action').html('');
      $(id + '-name').text(players[p].name);
      $(id + '-total').html(players[p].score);
      $(id + '-roll').html('--');
      $(id + '-round').html('--');
      $(id + '-dice').html('--');
  }
  $('#p' + idToPlay + '-action').html('<b>** Its your turn! **</>');  
}

//business logic for dice
function Dice() {
    this.diceValue=1;
  this.roll=0;
  this.round=0;
}

function Player(name) {
  this.name = name
  this.score = 0;
  players.push(this);
}
//global Players
players = [];
new Player("John");
new Player("Peter");

maxNumberPlayers = players.length;
dice = new Dice();
idToPlay = -1;//first player will be choosen by initGame

function switchPlayers() {
  displayResult();
  if(++idToPlay == maxNumberPlayers) idToPlay = 0;
  dice.round = 0;
  $( 'span[id$="-action"]').html('');
  $('#p' + idToPlay + '-action').html('<b>** Its your turn! **</>'); 
}

Dice.prototype.rollDice = function() {
  this.diceValue = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
  if (this.diceValue === 1) {
    this.roll = 0;
    this.round = 0
  } else {
    this.roll = this.diceValue;
    this.round += this.roll;
    }
}

Player.prototype.calcScore = function(isHoldButton = false) {
    dice.rollDice();
  if (dice.roll === 0) {
    dice.round = 0;
    switchPlayers();
  } else {
    this.round += dice.roll;
    displayResult();
  }
}

function displayResult(){
      let id = '#p' + idToPlay;
      $(id + '-name').html(players[idToPlay].name);
      $(id + '-total').html(players[idToPlay].score);
      $(id + '-roll').html(dice.roll);
      $(id + '-round').html(dice.round);
      $(id + '-dice').html(dice.diceValue);
}




//ui logic 
$(document).ready(function() {
  initGame();
    $("button.btn-roll").click(function() {
      players[idToPlay].calcScore();
  });
    $("button.btn-hold").click(function() {
      players[idToPlay].score += dice.round;
        switchPlayers();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <title>Pig Dice!</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Rule: If you roll a 1, you will receive 0 roll points for the round and it will be the other player's turn.
</p>
  <div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="player-0-panel active">
        <div class="player-name"><span id="p0-name">Player 1</span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span id="p0-action"></span></div>
        <div class="player0-score">
          <p>Dice points:<span id="p0-dice"></span>
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Roll points:<span id="p0-roll"></span>
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Round points:<span id="p0-round"></span>
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>total:<span id="p0-total"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="player-1-panel">
        <div class="player-name"><span id="p1-name">Player 1</span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span id="p1-action"></span></div>
        <div class="player1-score">
          <p>Dice points:<span id="p1-dice"></span>
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Roll points:<span id="p1-roll"></span>
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Round points:<span id="p1-round"></span>
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>total:<span id="p1-total"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>


      <button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark"></i>New game</button>
      <button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
      <button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>

    <img src="img/die5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice die1">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```